# If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, exists $M,\varepsilon>0$ such that $|v|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow (a+v\in U\text{ and }|f(a+v)-f(a)|\leq M|v|)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be a open set and $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $a\in U$. How to prove that there exists $M>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that, if $|v|<\varepsilon$, than $a+v\in U$ and $|f(a+v)-f(a)|\leq M|v|$?

Thanks.

Comment: Right. After 60+ questions, I think we can ask you to **add your thoughts** about the questions you ask.

Comment: @Did Sorry. I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Then we've got a problem ([Houston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston,_We%27ve_Got_a_Problem)): anybody moderately familiar with the definition of a differential should have an idea (even false) of something to try (and perhaps this something will fail, but this is no big deal). If you have no idea whatsoever about what is happening, how to write an answer that will help you? To begin with, what is the meaning of "$f$ is differentiable at $a$"? (Unrelated: why did you delete your previous comment?)

Comment: @Did "how to write an answer that will help you?" answer: in the following link there are more then 50 examples http://math.stackexchange.com/users/70305/perguntador. (I deleted the previous comment because I think the last looks better).

Comment: Surely you realize that your last comment sounds awfully like "I do not care about the rules of the site and I will not follow them as long as I get answers to my homework questions simply by copying them here".

Comment: @Did You are wrong (because do my homework is not my aim here), but seems right (because the most of my questions has no comment about what I tried). In the next questions, I will follow the rules of the site. Ok? Sorry for my comments and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall if $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable then for $\|h\|<\delta$ (choose $h$ small neough that a ball fits inside $U$ which can be done since its open)

$\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df_{x}(h)|}{\|h\|}<\epsilon$.

So by reverse triangle inequality and multiplying by $\|h\|$

(i.e $|f(x+h)-f(x)|-|Df_{x}(h)|\le|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df_{x}(h)|$ and $|f(x+h)-f(x)|-|Df_{x}(h)|<\epsilon\|h\|$)

we get

$|f(x+h)-f(x)|<|Df_{x}(h)|+\epsilon\|h\|\le(\|Df_{x}\|+\epsilon)\|h\|=M\|h\|$. Now take $x=a$, choose a direction, $v$, for $h$ (that is take $h=v$ for $v$ in the $\delta$ ball about $0$ from before). $M>0$ being the sum of two non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try to help you out. If someone finds some mistake I didn't see, please correct me.

Since $f : U \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $a$, there is a linear transformation, namely the derivative $Df(a) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $v$ with $a+v \in U$:

$$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)(v)|}{|v|}=0$$

By the triangle inequality we have:

$$\frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)(v)|}{|v|}\leq \frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)|+|Df(a)(v)|}{|v|}$$

Now, by the definition of limit, we can select $r > 0$ greater than the right hand side of the above inequality, and there will be $\varepsilon_1 >0$ such that if $|v|<\varepsilon_1$, then:

$$\frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)(v)|}{|v|}<r$$

We must assure yet that $a+v \in U$. So, since $U$ is open there is some ball of radius $\varepsilon_2$ centered at $a$ contained in $U$. Thus, if $a + v = b$, if $|v| = |b-a| < \varepsilon_2$ we are assured that $a+v \in U$, so we take $\varepsilon = \min\{\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2\}$ and $a+v \in U$ and in the same time, we will have the desired inequality. So supposing $|v| < \varepsilon$ we will have:

$$\frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)-Df(a)(v)|}{|v|}\leq \frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)|+|Df(a)(v)|}{|v|} < r$$

And thus $|f(a+v)-f(a)|<r|v|-|Df(a)(v)|$. Now, since $Df(a)$ is linear, there is $k$ such that $|Df(a)(v)|\leq k|v|$ and hence if $|v|<\varepsilon$, we have $|f(a+v)-f(a)|<M|v|$ where $M=r-k$, showing that there is $\varepsilon$ and $M$ with $|f(a+v)-f(a)|<M|v|$ as desired.